# echo image stored in variable

Tags: php, variables, youtube-api, echo

Ive been stuck on this all day now. Im making a script using the youtube API. Im trying to display the youtube thumbnail. I can echo the image in plain html and php at the end of the code, but im having problems getting it to echo in this part.

Before i post the code, i have the thumbnail images stored in a variable

```
$imgsrc="<img src=http://img.youtube.com/vi/".$searchResult['id']      ['videoId']."/hqdefault.jpg height=125 width=125>";
```

and the code in where im trying to echo

```
 // Add each result to the appropriate list, and then display the lists of
// matching videos, channels, and playlists.
foreach ($searchResponse['items'] as $searchResult) {
  switch ($searchResult['id']['kind']) {  
    case 'youtube#video':  
      $videos .= sprintf('<li><img src="'.$imgsrc.'">; %s (%s)</li>', $searchResult['snippet']['title'],  
        $searchResult['id']['videoId']."<a href=/video.php?".$searchResult['id']['videoId']." target=_blank>   Watch This Video</a>");  
      break;  
    case 'youtube#channel':
      $channels .= sprintf('<li>%s (%s)</li>',
          $searchResult['snippet']['title'], $searchResult['id']['channelId']);
      break;
    case 'youtube#playlist':
      $playlists .= sprintf('<li>%s (%s)</li>',
          $searchResult['snippet']['title'], $searchResult['id']['playlistId']);
      break;
  }
}
```

Any help will be greatly appriecated

a kind sole posted the answer then deleted his answer, this is what was needed:

```
  foreach ($searchResponse['items'] as $searchResult) {
 $imgsrc="<img src=http://img.youtube.com/vi/".$searchResult['id']
               ['videoId']."/hqdefault.jpg height=125 width=125>";
  switch ($searchResult['id']['kind']) {  
    case 'youtube#video':  
      $videos .= sprintf('<li>'.$imgsrc.'; %s (%s)</li>', $searchResult['snippet']['title'],  
        $searchResult['id']['videoId']."<a href=/video.php?".$searchResult['id']['videoId']." target=_blank>   Watch This Video</a>");  
      break;
```

If the answer appears again, i'll accept it

thanks guys

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Do you get an error? What are you expecting to see? What actually happens?

Comment: With the coded posted above, i get this:

    <img src="&lt;img src=http://img.youtube.com/vi//hqdefault.jpg height=125 width=125&gt;">

It doesnt echo the videoid, i also see i have a double image tag, whoops!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
foreach ($searchResponse['items'] as $searchResult) {
   $imgsrc = "<img src='http://img.youtube.com/vi/".$searchResult['id']['videoId']."/hqdefault.jpg' height='125' width='125'>";

   $videos .= sprintf('<li>%s %s (%s)</li>', $imgsrc , $searchResult['snippet']['title'],  
   $searchResult['id']['videoId']."<a href=/video.php?".$searchResult['id']['videoId']." target=_blank>   Watch This Video</a>");
```

OR

```
foreach ($searchResponse['items'] as $searchResult) {
   $imgsrc="http://img.youtube.com/vi/".$searchResult['id']['videoId']."/hqdefault.jpg";
   $videos .= sprintf('<li>'.$imgsrc.' %s (%s)</li>', $searchResult['snippet']['title'],  
    $searchResult['id']['videoId']."<a href=/video.php?".$searchResult['id']['videoId']." target=_blank>   Watch This Video</a>");
```